# What is the [svn-revision] tag doing on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I just spotted the [svn-revision](/questions/tagged/svn-revision) tag on Meta. Is this tag really required here?

There is no tag wiki and only 2 questions are tagged under it. Should we start retagging?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions before retagging?

Comment: @AzizShaikh Thinking of options.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 questions tagged under [svn-revision](/questions/tagged/svn-revision) are related to the build/version number of Meta Stack Overflow. So I believe, the tag is a valid tag and need not be burninated. Reminiscent of the days before Stack Exchange [moved away from SVN](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/).

Comment: the rev "1399" in `2013.9.4.1399` at the bottom of the page is actually the build number, and has no relation with the revision. We use Mercurial and the corresponding revision looks like "f629972a3xxx" which is shown nowhere on the site.